# Where is the best place to log soap request to logstash with some additional information

Tags: java, logback, spring-ws

I have logback appender in my application to log message into logstash:

```
<appender name="logstashSocket" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashAccessTcpSocketAppender">
    <destination>${logstash.destination}</destination>

    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashAccessEncoder" />
</appender>
```

now I need to decide where to log my soap request. There is 2 options. Before unmarshalling and use some spring interceptor or after when I already got jaxbElement which I will convert to string xml. Problem is that I need to log also some meta data(elements) which are included in soap request what is easy to extract in second option but hard in first when request is not unmarshalled. So any advice where to log my soap request ?

Answer (score 0):

As early as possible; the document might not be valid XML and might not validate either. Cache the request as a string, and use a StAX parser to extract the relevant fields.

Comment: hm ok but it is ok when I dont log invalid XML or XML which is not valid agains XSD

Comment: Famous last words